# Trying to move an object moves the texture on the object instead

Tags: objects, gizmo

So I have somehow turned this on and I dont know how to turn it off again, the gizmo that usually moves an object is now moving a bigger version of itself, and I dont know how to change it back

[image: You can see the problem im having here]

Answer (score 2):

Turn off this option in the N properties panel.

[image]